# How do I remapping solidity import in config file?

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

This is my file structure.

```
contracts
|-packages
| |- package1
| | | package1-1.sol
| | | package1-2.sol
| |- package2
| | | package2-1.sol
| | | package2-2.sol
| file1.sol
| file2.sol
```

In my `file1.sol`, I want to import `package1`, like this `package/package1-1.sol`:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;

import "package1/package1-1.sol"; // <-- import

interface test is Package1 {

}
```

But it can't parse, I rempping `package1` -> `./packages/package1`.

---

I try to use command:

```bash
solc contracts/file1.sol --base-path . --include-path=contracts/packages
```

It can run successfully, but I want to config in `metadata.json` file or other files. How do I config and run it?